# Changing a Specific Value in a Matrix of Dictionaries

Tags: python

I want to change a specific value in a 5x5 matrix of dictionaries, here's my code:

```
matrix = [[{"value": 1}]*5]*5

matrix[0][0]["value"] = 4

print(matrix)
```

Instead of changing one value, it changes all of them:

```
[[{'value': 4}, {'value': 4}, {'value': 4}, {'value': 4}, {'value': 4}], [{'value': 4}, {'value': 4}, {'value': 4}, {'value': 4}, {'value': 4}], [{'value': 4}, {'value': 4}, {'value': 4}, {'value': 4}, {'value': 4}], [{'value': 4}, {'value': 4}, {'value': 4}, {'value': 4}, {'value': 4}], [{'value': 4}, {'value': 4}, {'value': 4}, {'value': 4}, {'value': 4}]]
```

Shouldn't the code only change one value, like this:

```
[[{'value': 4}, {'value': 1}, {'value': 1}, {'value': 1}, {'value': 1}], [{'value': 1}, {'value': 1}, {'value': 1}, {'value': 1}, {'value': 1}], [{'value': 1}, {'value': 1}, {'value': 1}, {'value': 1}, {'value': 1}], [{'value': 1}, {'value': 1}, {'value': 1}, {'value': 1}, {'value': 1}], [{'value': 1}, {'value': 1}, {'value': 1}, {'value': 1}, {'value': 1}]]
```

What do I have to change in the code to get this output?

Comment: The usage of `*` is the reason changing one sublist leads to the change in all the other sublists. Use a for loop or a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Multiplying](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common) a list by n simply repeats its contents n times. Therefore, this

```
[{"value": 1}]*5
```

will create a new list with 5 references to the same dict `{"value": 1}`. Since all list items reference the same object, updating any of them affects the others.

Instead, use list comprehensions to create distinct objects:

```
matrix = [[{"value": 1} for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]
matrix[0][0]["value"] = 4
print(matrix)
```